# I've noticed the water from the sink won't heat up, while the water in both bathrooms heats fine.

Tags: plumbing, leak, water-heater

I've been renting this home for more than a year and there have been a lot of plumbing issues - mostly leaks, but the water in the kitchen has always heated fine. There is a leak under the sink as well, though I can't see it dripping, I can just see that the cabinet floor is wet. The hot water is working in both of our bathrooms, so I figured it wasn't the hot water heater. What could cause something like this? My landlord drags her feet with getting these things fixed, and when she does send a plumber out it's always one of her friends and he doesn't actually fix anything. Maybe if I know what needs to be done I can hire my own person and deduct it from rent.

Comment: If you turn off the cold water under the sink, then open the tap to the full hot position, does the water get hot? Does it even come out at all?

Comment: Does the kitchen faucet have a single control, or two separate controls for hot and cold?

Comment: Not a fix, but don't expect to deduct the cost of a repair from your rent without a written agreement from the landlord.

Comment: Does it have a single point instant heater unit installed under the sink?